# Can I match and replace data if only a few of the characters match?

Tags: r, matching, shapefile

I want to create a map. And, my data set names don't match exactly with the shapefile names. For example:

**Data set 1:**

```
Name_district Unmployment_rate    
Amatali 101
Amtli 111
Aamatali 111
Bamna 122
Baamna 111
Baamuuna 222
B.Baria 222
Brahammanbaria 221
```

**Shape Data:**

```
Name_district Shape_polygon    
Amtali 101
Bamuna 122
Bramhanbaria 222
```

If I use `inner_join`, the data map won't work because I need an exact shapefile name in the data file.

I have round 12k observations in `Dataset1` for 5000 shapefile observations. The `Name_district` is not properly written, so that's why it's 12k, while the unique value should be around 5k.

I would like to know is there is any function I could create where the `Name_district` would be replaced with the accurate name from shapefile if the `Name_district` in the dataset matches 50%-60% correct to the shapefile name.

Comment: What program are you using? You've tagged this question with [R], but it doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using `fuzzy_join`? You can also adjust the maximum distance (`max_dist`) for use in joining.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

stringdist_join(df1, df2, by = "Name_district", distance_col = NULL, max_dist = 3)
```

**Output**

```
  Name_district.x Unmployment_rate Name_district.y Shape_polygon
1         Amatali                1          Amtali             a
2           Amtli                2          Amtali             a
3        Aamatali                3          Amtali             a
4           Bamna                4          Bamuna             b
5          Baamna                5          Bamuna             b
6        Baamuuna                6          Bamuna             b
7  Brahammanbaria                8    Bramhanbaria             c
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Name_district = c("Amatali", "Amtli", "Aamatali", "Bamna", "Baamna", "Baamuuna", "B.Baria", "Brahammanbaria"),
  Unmployment_rate = 1:8
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  Name_district = c("Amtali", "Bamuna", "Bramhanbaria"),
  Shape_polygon = letters[1:3]
)
```